# IOS - Write to UITextField from another class in the IOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, user-interface, uitextfield

I have method in `ViewController`:

```
(void) writeInViewController:(NSString *)var {
         NSLog(@"Var: %@", var);

}
```

I send value to this method(writeInViewController) from another class it's receive the value and print it in the Debug Area but I can't write to the User Interface  `(textfield.text = var)`
I need to add text to the `UITextField` from this method

Thanks

Comment: You create your another class in your ViewController ? In this case, you can give your UITextField to your another class.

Comment: You are not give delegate of textfield in your Outlate.

Comment: open this link it definately helpful for you   


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178600/pass-a-value-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong your value getting null when you are assign to UITextField, do one thing create one instance variable or property then assign that value to variable then assign to UITextField it will work.